# What's the difference between .userInitiated and .userInteractive in GCD?

Tags: ios, swift3

I would like to know what's difference between them, I am trying to update something in the UI thus I must do it using the main thread but not sure which of them I should use to accomplish what I want.

Thanks

Comment: Very good described in docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH39-SW1

Comment: The docs aren't actually good. Look to the kernel source instead: https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.1.46/osfmk/kern/thread_policy.c.auto.html

User Interactive has highest tier (tier 0) for throughput and latency, while user initiated is tier 1 for both. The throughput and latency values are used by the scheduler: throughput is used as the "urgency" value to the scheduler backend, while latency is used to control timer coalescing level. You can use `taskinfo` cmd to inspect reported values.

Comment: A better question is what's the relation between qos userinteractive and "realtime" thread constraint. Based on source, answer seems to be that realtime has priority over everything, surprisingly even the kernel, and will always be scheduled first if runnable. Out of the non-realtime userspace classes though, userInteractive gets first cut. But please don't abuse realtime, it should not be used for computation heavy workloads.

Comment: I should clarify, besides the throughput and latency the qos is primarily used to determine the priority of the process, on a level from 0-127 (with the 96-127 range reserved for realtime). While user-initiated and legacy (default) qos have same tiers for latency/throughput, user-initiated is higher in terms of priority.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

"User initiated" means the user directly requested this operation, and is likely waiting, but the UI itself is not desperate for a result. "Fetch new tweets because the user performed pull-to-refresh" or "recalculate the tip." These things need to happen quickly, but not immediately. Once the computation is completed, you probably won't ask for it again immediately.

"User interactive" means the user is directly interacting with the result of this operation in real time. The UI needs a result right now or lagging will occur. You will probably be requesting this operation quickly and repeatedly. This is the highest priority.

For full details on these classes, see ["Building Responsive and Efficient Apps with GCD."](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/718)

Comment: so then I should use .userInteractive for purposes of updating the UI

Comment: Interactively. Many things update the UI. The question is whether the user is currently directly interacting with the thing that you're updating. If this block is delayed, will the UI stutter or lag? That's user interactive.

Comment: Reasonable rule of thumb: if this block takes longer than 1/60 of a second to complete (from the time it takes to schedule until it finishes), then clearly it isn't interactive. If it being delayed by 1/60 second would cause UI problems, then it is. The user interactive priority should be rare in your program. If it's common, then you've probably misunderstood what "priority" means. It's all about what can be delayed. If everything is high priority, nothing is.

Comment: Remember, the main queue has the highest priority anyway and is serial, so if you're already dispatching to the main queue, it isn't going to matter. This matters for things you run on non-main queues.

Comment: so is it just a priority? `.background` & `.default` seems are the slowest ones and `.userInitiated` & `.userInteractive` are the fastest (best performance) ones?

Comment: Low priority tasks don't run any slower than high priority tasks, so it's not about slow/fast or performance. Higher priority tasks are scheduled before lower priority tasks, so very low-priorty tasks (`.background`) may  not be scheduled for a long time if there are higher priority tasks in queue. And in some cases (such as low-power mode), `.background` tasks may not be scheduled at all. But once they are scheduled, they often (though not always) run at the same speed as higher-priority tasks. (Sometimes there's thread-prioritization that may impact scheduling at a lower level then queue).

Comment: If the details are important to you, see the linked WWDC video. Using priorities is pretty simple most of the time. But the full details of precisely how those priorities are applied are sometimes complex and subject to change. Luckily you generally don't have to worry about that. Just pick your queue based on the descriptions (not by trying to second-guess how it will be implemented). https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH39-SW1

Comment: @RobNapier I tested every priority for one of my task and with `.userInitiated` & `.userInteractive` it have been executed the fastest, for example with `.background` it was 800 ms, when with `.userInteractive` it was 650 ms (I tested a lot, and result was always like this). So I know now that I always should set `.userInteractive` if I want thread process something faster. I have a habit of measuring code execution time, have functions for it. P.S. please mention my name **@user924** when commenting

Comment: @user924 "So I know now that I always should set .userInteractive if I want thread process something faster." This is definitely not true. You should not set `.userInteractive` unless the user is waiting for the result interactively and the time for the block to execute is under 1/60 of second. 650ms is far too long for a user interactive method. `userInitiated` is appropriate for things that the user has actively requested. Micro-optimizing this way is extremely fragile, and you can easily hurt the overall performance of your app by misusing queues.

Comment: In particular you have to be very careful of priority inversions when you overuse the `user` queues. The OS has techniques for fixing priority inversions to avoid deadlock, but they can cause very low priority tasks to run in the wrong order and block other high priority tasks, causing an overall degradation. Making each individual block run as soon as possible does not guarantee a high-performing system. QoS levels also have other subtle meanings besides just ordering. They should not be used arbitrarily to mean "fast." Apple created a system with names other than "high/low" on purpose.

Comment: @RobNapier I tested neural nets (Core ML) on quite old iPad, after detection (which takes 650 with `.userInteractive`)  I had to show on display what it detected (for example rects on camera frame, so user could see it). Of course on iPhone X such task would work much faster and I could just set `.background`

Comment: That's exactly the use case for `.userInitiated`. What problem did you have with that QoS?

Comment: @RobNapier no, actually I said that `userInitiated & userInteractive` (both) were the fastest (pretty similar speed), and `.background & .default` much slower (especially `.background` - the slowest). So I'm okay with `.userInitiated`

Comment: And that brings around to the point: use the level that describes your situation. Your user has asked for something and they can't really move forward until you're done processing. It's not interactive, but the user is waiting. That's `.userInitiated`, which also happens to use the fastest threads. `.background` is not just "the slowest." It carries a lot of other information, such as that the app could be fine for a very long time (hours or days) without running it at all. It happens to be the slowest, but it might not even run, which is completely different than a thread with low priority.

Comment: From Apple docs: ```Because higher priority work is performed more quickly and with more resources than lower priority work, it typically requires more energy than lower priority work.```